# angular-cli ng serve --open not working in Safari but works in firefox

Tags: angular-cli

On X Yosomite,

running `ng new my-app` there is no issue with new App creation. Running `ng serve --open` opens a tab in Safari browser but only shows default `src/index.html` file.

Also live updates to index.html are taken and shown in the browser.

However when I open URL `http://localhost:4200` in Firefox, then I can see the proper result (the result of `App component` and `Module`).

My question is:

**Does `ng serve --open` not work with Safari?**

It is a bit annoying because I can't set Firefox as default browser from Angular CLI.

Answer (score 0):

it might not be a browser issue.

Have you tried to use `ng serve --live-reload --open` 
I was having a similar issue with `ng serve --open`

The docs at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve claim that live reload is on by default but for me this was not true. i cant say why at this time.